# How to fix setting an array element with a sequence error?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, numpy

I am trying to make a keras functional model that solves Sentiment Analysis through the amazon database. I am trying to split the input data into 4 different tensors that can be individual feed in to yield a concatenated output that gets processed (there is a reason behind it). However, when training it, it spits out the error of ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence and directs me to the model.fit() line which I could not find an issue with, so I assume it is the inputs to the network.

Code:
https://pastebin.com/Fc33jEbv

Thank you for your time.